# Aviso de erro projeto Mavem

Tags: java

Formatei meu PC e importei meu projeto Maven, só que fica aparecendo o aviso:

> "This project has the JPA facet, but no JPA project could be created.
>   See the error log for more details."

O projeto roda normalmente!!

Poderiam me dar uma luz!!

Answer (score 0):

Este é um problema de configuração do projeto. 
Para resolver este problema basta ir até as propriedades do projeto, e no `project facets` e desmarcar  e aplicar as alterações.

Comment: Ok vou fazer e verificar se da certo!!

Comment: Apareceram outros problemas após o procedimento acima, tive que criar outro workspace e importar um projeto que eu salvei antes de acontecer isso. Mas valeu pela dica.